# How to lock the orientation to Landscape in react native android?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm creating an Android app using react-native. **I need to create the app for the Nexus 9 tab in Landscape mode.** I already created the Nexus 9 tab emulator in Android studio with Android 10.0 x86 API level 29. **The problem is, App is still locked to portrait mode.**

To make the view in Landscape mode, I added `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` to the `<activity>` in AndroidManifest.xml as follows

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.sipandroid">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Even after I modified to the above code, **App is still locked to the portrait mode**. How can I take this to the landscape mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use this tag in the body of specific activity which you created
android:orientation="vertical
 `<activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" />`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. **The problem was the Android version and the API level**. I changed it from 10.0 API level 29 to 9.0 API level 28 and now it's working